# How to enable/disable sharepoint 2010 farm scoped features using powershell?

Tags: 2010, powershell, feature-activation, farm, feature-scope

I've got all I need to know about the feature. I just want to enable it.
When enabling site, web or webapplication scoped feature I use to call this cmdlet:

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity <feature_name_or_Gui> -Url <scope> -confirm:$false
```

What is the cmdlet to do the same with a farm scoped feature. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skip the `-Url` parameter

```
Enable-SPFeature -Identity <feature_name_or_Guid> -confirm:$false
```

More found on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/ff607803.aspx)